# using page-object-gem obtain count of nested elements

Tags: page-object-gem

What is the most efficient way to obtain a count of nested elements using the page-object-gem

Given some sample HTML

```
<ul :id="templateFields">
    <li class="review">Review</li>
    <li class="review">Assign</li>
    <li class="generate">Retrieve</li>
</ul>
```

Where we have our page-object defined as

```
class MyPage
  include  PageObject

  unordered_list(:steps, :id => 'templateFields')
end
```

Looking for the count of the nested ordered_list elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unordered list element has a `list_items` method that returns its `li` elements. You could count how many elements are returned:

```
page.steps_element.list_items.count
#=> 3
```

If you do this frequently, you may be better of defining an accessor for the list items themselves.

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  unordered_list(:steps, :id => 'templateFields')
  list_items(:step_item, :css => '#templateFields li')
end
```

Then you would simpliy call:

```
page.step_item_elements.count
#=> 3
```